# How can I use my fastai model with my flask app?

Tags: python, flask, fast-ai

I am trying to integrate an image color detector I have trained with fastai in my flask application.
There is a custom function exported with the learner for the model to be loaded. The function is getImages. I am getting the following error because it cant find the function in the main namespace:

`Can't get attribute 'getImages' on <module '__main__' from 'C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Documents\\MyApp\\Scraper\\env\\Scripts\\flask.exe\\__main__.py'>`

How do I add it to that namescope so I can load the model? Do I need to edit the flask module? or is there another way.

```
@app.route('/api/getRelatedPages', methods=['POST'])
async def getRelatedPagesEnd():
    requestData = request.get_json()
    productInfo = Model.Product(requestData['pageContent'])
    with set_posix_windows():
        colorClassfier ={
            'name': 'Color',
            'Model': load_learner(Colors.getColorClassifierPath()),
            'Target': 'image',
        }
        await productInfo.getSimilarProducts(colorClassfier)
```

here is where I load the model in run.py. it is causing the error because it is trying to load the model and cant find the function in the **main** scope because that is where it was available during training. In a simple python scripts I can just add the getImage function in the main namescope to make it available.
here is the function:

```
def getImages(d): return d['imagePath']
```

but in a flask app the main scope starts from the flask.exe and I don't know how to add it.

Comment: We necessitate more code to solve your problem. Make sure you imported the model properly.

Comment: ok I will add some more.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by starting my flask application using `app.run()` and then running command `python run.py`. Instead of having the FLASK_APP env variable declared and using the command `flask run`

this made my file run.py the main namescope.